# AWS - how to prevent load balancer from terminating instances under load?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm writing a web-service that packs up customer data into zip-files, then uploads them to S3 for download. It is an on-demand process, and the amount of data can range from a few Megabytes to multiple Gigabytes, depending on what data the customer orders.
Needless to say, scalability is essential for such a service. But I'm having trouble with it. Packaging the data into zip-files has to be done on the local harddrive of a server instance.

But the load balancer is prone to terminating instances that are still working. I have taken a look at scaling policies:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-termination.html

But what I need doesn't seem to be there. The issue shouldn't be so difficult: I set the scale metric to CPU load, and scale down when it goes under 1%. But I need a guarantee that the exact instance will be terminated that breached the threshold, not another one that's still hard at work, and the available policies don't seem to present me with that option. Right now, I am at a loss how to achieve this. Can anybody give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have configured an **Auto Scaling group** with scaling policies based upon CPU Utilization.

Please note that an **Elastic Load Balancer will never terminate an Amazon EC2 instance** -- if a Load Balancer health check fails, it will merely stop serving traffic to that EC2 instance until it again passes the health checks. It is possible to configure Auto Scaling to use ELB health checks, in which case Auto Scaling will terminate any instances that ELB marks as unhealthy.

Therefore, it would appear that Auto Scaling is responsible for terminating your instances, as a result of your scaling policies. You say that you wish to **terminate specific instances that are unused**. However, this is not the general intention of Auto Scaling. Rather, Auto Scaling is used to provide a pool of resources that can be scaled by launching new instances and terminating unwanted instances. Metrics that trigger Auto Scaling are typically based upon aggregate metrics across the whole Auto Scaling group (eg **average** CPU Utilization).

Given that Amazon EC2 instances are charged by the hour, it is often a good idea to keep instance running longer -- "**Scale Out quickly, Scale In slowly**".

Once Auto Scaling decides to terminate an instance (which it selects via a [termination policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-termination.html#custom-termination-policy)), use an Auto Scaling [lifecycle hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) to delay the termination until ready (eg, copying log files to S3, or waiting for a long process to complete).

If you *do* wish to terminate an instance after it has completed a particular workload, there is no need to use Auto Scaling -- just have the instance Shutdown when it is finished, and set the [Shutdown Behavior](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingInstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior) to `terminate` to automatically terminate the instance upon shutdown. (This assumes that you have a process to launch new instances when you have work you wish to perform.)

Stepping back and looking at your total architecture, it would appear that you have a Load Balancer in front of web servers, and you are performing the Zip operations on the web servers? This is not a scalable solution. It would be better if your web servers pushed a message into an **Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS)** queue, and then your fleet of back-end servers processed messages from the queue. This way, your front-end can continue receiving requests regardless of the amount of processing underway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) to perform actions before an instance is terminated. You could use this to wait for the processing to finish before proceeding with the instance termination.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is Instance Protection, which is actually mentioned a bit more towards the bottom of the document that you linked to. As long as you have work being performed on a particular instance, it should not be automatically terminated by the Auto-Scaling Group (ASG).

[Check out this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-instance-protection-for-auto-scaling/), on the official AWS blog, that conceptually talks about how you can use Instance Protection to prevent work from being prematurely terminated.

Comment: I have in fact seen that, but it seems ill-suited for automation.